# Pass the name of a file to a void main, through a graphical interface in Java

Tags: java

i doing a program to calculate the critical path method from a DAG, program logic is perfect, but I have a problem trying to integrate a graphical user interface. The interface lets me through a JFileChooser to choose the input file for the program, but I do not know how to pass that parameter to the function "readfile", located in the main action.

Herés the code of the void main:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrameConFondo jf = new EjemploJFrameConFondo();
                jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                jf.setTitle("CPM");
                jf.setVisible(true);
                readfile(route);
               ////I need to pass a filename to the program which calculate the critical path,
            }
        });
    }
}
```

here's the code of the function "readfile":

```
public static void leer_archivo(String fileName){
        try{
       File archivo=new File(fileName);
       FileReader fr= new FileReader(archivo);
       BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(fr);
       String linea;


       linea=br.readLine();
       c=Integer.parseInt(linea);
       for(int i=0;i<c;i++){
           CrearCaso(br, i+1);
       }
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
```

I'm doing this action for the button on the interface for the file selection, and I want the name of that file in some way can be sent to void main to be able to use the function "readfile":

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed
         JFileChooser filechooser = new JFileChooser();
         int option = filechooser.showOpenDialog (this);
         if (option==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            cajaTexto.setText(filechooser.getSelectedFile().getPath());

        }
```

I hope someone can give me a hand with this, I'm stuck with this for a few days and I'm really new in the world Java. I did not put the whole code because there are several classes and several lines of code.

Comment: @MoritzPetersen, Oh I completely misread the question.  Let me fix the damage I just did...

Comment: 1) The `main()` is called.  2) The GUI appears on-screen 3) The user browses to & selects a file 4) Call `readFile()`  -- The thing that is confusing me is why you think it is a good idea to call the `main()` again after the first time.  The only reason for the main method to read a file name is if that has been passed as the file to 'open in the default program' or similar.  *"I did not put the whole code because there are several classes and several lines of code."*  The problem could be solved with 1 class & several lines of code.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your code in two places. I assume, that the button action is actually working. I assume, that your "main" class is called "MyProgram".

```java
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed
     JFileChooser filechooser = new JFileChooser();
     int option = filechooser.showOpenDialog (this);
     if (option==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        String filename = filechooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
        cajaTexto.setText(filename);
        // call main():
        MyProgram.main(new String[] { filename });
    }

public static void main(String args[]) {
            // assign file name
    final String route = args[0];
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrameConFondo jf = new EjemploJFrameConFondo();
                jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                jf.setTitle("CPM");
                jf.setVisible(true);
                readfile(route);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: using `args` is probably ok in this case but it's best not to risk it when it can be solved otherwise (like a global variable handler) :)

Comment: Solvent my problem I simply copied
all methods that were useful as calculations, print, etc, to the same class of the interface, and only invoked the interface from the void main. I do not know if it's the best solution or the most elegant but it worked. What do you say?

Comment: Calling the GUI from the main merhod is fine. But I strongly recommend to separate GUI and business logic. Therefore you should implement a third class which implements your logic and pass the file name to it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let me check if I understand your question properly...
You have a function `readfile(String filename)` that you want to call inside your `main` function.
You can get the path to the file using `filechooser.getSelectedFile().getPath()`.
In this case you can export the selected path into a static variable of a public class.

So make a new class:

```
public class Globals
{
  private static String FilePath;
  public static String GetFilePath()
  {
    return FilePath;
  }
  public static void SetFilePath(String NewPath)
  {
    FilePath = NewPath;
  }
}
```

Set it with button using:

```
Globals.SetFilePath(filechooser.getSelectedFile().getPath());
```

And then use it so:

```
readfile(Globals.GetFilePath());
```

Notes*
This isn't necessarily the best solution available. It involves least changes to *already exising* source code though. 
Also, please excuse my Pascal notation, habit from C#.